# OpenAI with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I am trying to use the openAIApi in order to get a response to generate text for my school project. I was wondering why the module is not found. I already installed via
npm i openai
and it is in my node_modules folder.
I checked the key and it was correct for my project, but it seems that my script does not know where to locate openai at.

```
import { Configuration, openAIApi} from "openai";
```

The code is located in my public folder and I am running node server.js
Error: TypeError: Module name, 'openai' does not resolve to a valid URL.

Comment: are you using deno or bun?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have openai listed in your package.json file, or if it is not there try running:

```
npm install --save openai
# or
yarn add openai
```

You can follow their official documentation for proper usage of Openai with Nodejs, below is the basic template you can use:

```
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI();

async function main() {
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [{ role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." }],
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  });

  console.log(completion.choices[0]);
}

main();
```

Here is the documentation link: https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart?context=node

Here is the video demonstration of Openai integration with Nodejs and then with Reactjs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ROkq1QNP3g

Answer (score 0):

what version u using now?

```
// Old v3
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

// new v4
import OpenAI from 'openai';
```

change your code

read this docs
https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart?context=node